# Venetians attracted to Mary Jane

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

[image]

**Across**
1/5. Trouble with battle making a neighbourhood essentially warmer (3,5,6)
10. *(See 14 down)*
11. Place with obstructed view to Venetians, perhaps attracted to Mary Jane (5,4)
12. Activity to enjoy in Venice: jumping a rope (5)
13. Reason to give out beer (9)
15/29d. Franklin and Hamilton's birthplace is a mountain (3,5)
16. Punishment contains moving (8)
19. Some threw a kebab party to honour the deceased (4)
20. Perhaps the Caribbean marine mammal lost its tail (3)
23. Old lady to perform a major piece (4)
25. Old Turks' secret plot to man stations (8)
27. Reportedly trendy lodging (3)
30. Comic Gabriel has new live opener – seem familiar? (4,1,4)
31. Another execution pushing you back to return half-heartedly (5)
33. Insight in education payment (9)
34. Object to fine facing government's leader (5)
35. Microsoft is behind trend making electronic equipment (6)
36. SEAT putting Toyota's leaders behind bars with conclusions of auto scandal (8)

**Down**
1. Ugly skin mostly associated with debts (7)
2. Bringing up some established literary character (5)
3. A city in denial? I can tell (8)
4. Some brag about economic sanctions (8)
6. Strange work for Bond villain (6)
7. Head honcho to lead a grandmother (3,6)
8. Severe case of typhoid fever among former European maritime empire's leaders (7)
9. A distant view in Virginia is brought closer (5)
14/10a. South Asian city censoring bottom in lewd hiney-shaking (3,5)
17. .Net domain incorrectly named (9)
18/28. Right-wing movement previously known as "working ideology" south of Arizona (3-6)
21. Georgia's capital has a football club (8)
22. Request for assistance to get box to philosopher (8)
23. Left-wing philosophy of American comedian is primarily moderate (7)
24. An introduction to General Lee (3)
26. Country gal seen dancing (7)
28. *(See 18 down)*
29. *(See 15 across)*
32. Large animal's broken horn has iron tip (5)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Completed grid

> [image]

Across clues

> 1/5. "warmer" = HOT WATER + B(A->_O_)TTLE
>  11. "Place with obstructed view" = BLINDS+POT
>  12. "Activity to enjoy in Venice" = OPERA*
>  13. "Reason" = RATION+ALE
>  15/29d. "mountain" = BEN+NEVIS
>  16. "Punishment" = SANCTION*
>  19. "party to honour the deceased" = _W A KE_
>  20. "Perhaps the Caribbean" = SEA(-l)
>  23. "Old lady" = _M A MA_
>  25. "Old Turks" = _OT TO MANS_
>  27. "lodging" = INN ("in")
>  30. "seem familiar" = RI(N)GABEL*+L_
>  31. "Another execution" = RERUN (RETURN, remove T in TU ("half-heartedly"), move U forward ("pushing you back"))
>  33. "Insight" = IN+TUITION
>  34. "Object" = THIN+G_
>  35. "electronic equipment" = MODE+MS
>  36. "SEAT" = BARS+TO_+_O+_L

Down clues

> 1. "Ugly" = HIDE+(-i)OUS
>  2. "character" = _TIL DE_<
>  3. "A city" = _AL I CAN TE_
>  4. "economic sanctions" = EMBARGOS*
>  6. "Strange work" = "Bond villain" = ODDJOB (ddef)
>  7. "Head honcho" = TO+PB+A+NANA
>  8. "Severe" = EX(T_R)E_ M_ E_
>  9. "A distant view" = V(IS+_T)A
>  14/10a. "South Asian city" = NEW DELHI (-y)*
>  17. "named" = NOMINATED*
>  18/28. "Right-wing movement" = NE+ON+AZ+ISM
>  21. "football club" = AT(A)LANTA
>  22. "philosopher" = SO(CRATE)S
>  23. "Left-wing philosophy" = MARX+IS+M_
>  24. "Lee" = AN+G_
>  26. "Country" = SENEGAL*
>  32. "Large animal" = RH(I_)NO*